# Set a task to re-execute after a period of time (multithreading) Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an ExecutorService that will be assigned 3 tasks. Each task will connect to a website and fetch the data from it (using jsoup library). Each task will take about 0.5s to fetch the data. But sometimes, jsoup will fail to connect to that site and it's took more than 5s to throws SocketTimeoutException.

But I want that if one of the three tasks take more than 2s, jsoup will re-try to connect. Is there any solutions for this?

This is the example of my code:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

es.execute(() -> {
    task1: connect to website 1 and fetch data
});

es.execute(() -> {
    task2: connect to website 2 and fetch data
});

es.execute(() -> {
    task3: connect to website 3 and fetch data
});

es.shutdown();
```

Thanks everyone read this!

Comment: Look into [`Jsoup.parse(URL url, int timeoutMillis)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse(java.net.URL,int)).

Comment: yah. Thanks you for your help, but if the time exceed the timeout, jsoup will throw exception not re-try to connect. Problem still there..

Comment: Design a util for retry, or you can use off-the-shelf, for example:  ```https://kymr.github.io/2017/01/09/RetryUtils-with-java8/```